# How to remove bootstrap-sass from Ruby on Rails 5.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to remove bootstrap-sass 3.3.7 from ruby on rails. I installed *gem bootstrap-sass* a month ago. However, I created design by myself. So I would like to uninstall bootstrap-sass.

I tried

```
gem uninstall gem bootstrap-sass

rake assets:clean
```

but, bootstrap was not removed.

Comment: did you remove the bootstrap gem from your Gemfile? And did you remove the line `@import "bootstrap";` from your `application.scss` file?

Comment: Yes, I did. but, if I do 'rails s', rails said 'Could not find bootstrap-sass-3.3.7 in any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.'.

Comment: Is there still a reference to bootstrap in your Gemfile.lock file?

Comment: Perhaps, that's right. Is there any solution?

Comment: Yeah, you could remove your Gemfile.lock file and then run bundle install to update all your dependencies.

Comment: ah. Could I remove 'bootstrap' from Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Yeah you can, but you'll need to delete your Gemfile.lock file. When you run `bundle install` again, a new Gemfile.lock will be created with your updated dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! Bootstrap is removed!

Comment: Great! :) I just posted an answer, would you mind accepting / upvoting it if I helped you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next steps:

1. remove `bootstrap-sass` from the Gemfile of your project
2. `bundle && gem uninstall bootstrap-sass` to remove from the project dependencies and system
3. remove include of `bootstrap-sprockets` and `bootstrap` in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`
4. remove include of `bootstrap-sprockets` from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I did. However, rails said 'Could not find bootstrap-sass-3.3.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.'

Comment: Did you remove it from Gemfile and then run `bundle`?

Comment: Sure. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Hmm. Do you have gems that have dependencies `bootstrap-sass`? Have you tried to find `bootstrap-sass` in Gemfile.lock?

Comment: I find bootstrap-sass in Gemfile.lock. Could I remove it?

Comment: remove all file - it will be regenerated when you run `bundle` again

Comment: Thanks! Bootstrap is removed!

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove all traces of bootstrap from you `Gemfile.lock` file. To do that, simply remove the `Gemfile.lock` file and then run:

```
bundle install
```

This will re-create your `Gemfile.lock` with updated dependencies.